# Log4J application.log file not getting written to

Tags: java, linux, log4j, playframework, centos

I implemented a log4j.properties file in my conf/ directory just as instructed here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production#logging.

Locally on my workstation it works, my log output stopped appearing in my console and started appearing in my application.log file. This is the correct/expected behavior.

However this same application once copied to my production server does not log. The application.log is empty and remains empty.

This is all on centOS linux.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: did you set this vm argument in production server -Dlog4j.configuration=(path to log4j.xml or log4j.properties) on prod server

Comment: Are you using a full path to your log? Are you sure that the application is running where you think it is?  Have you tried removing the log file and running again?  Is the log file recreated?

Comment: The article that explains how to set this up has a comment that I don't understand, maybe this is related?                                                      "The above logging example assumes that conf is in the classpath, thats why application.log.path=/log4j.properties is set in application.conf . But conf is not added to classpath with the default play package. So add that and it will start working i.e. the log files will be created "

Answer (score 0):

Does your application has a permission to write application.log file? Maybe java process is started under user with insufficient write privellesges.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not a Linux guy unfortunately. I'm not sure how permissions work on Linux yet still learning. And I'm not sure what "user" play or java are running as.

Comment: If you think it may be a permissions issue, I can ask my linux ops team that setup the environment to investigate that angle.

Comment: In my career I have maybe one hundred of errors in linux related to permission. So when sympthoms are "Working on windows, not working on Linux" first of all I check permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys I'll investigate that angle.

Comment: BTW this isn't a permissions issue. With read write open to everyone, I don't know why play isn't able to write to it's log file. Anyone?